# change background color

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

I am wondering why sometimes I can change the webpage background color and sometimes I can't. For example, in some sites I just type in document.body.bgColor = "red" in the chrome console, and the background color changed temporarily. However, in the other sites like StackOverFlow, this doesn't work. Since my browser has already loaded the page, I should be able to change how to displays it locally. Why not? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Chrome you can use the DOM inspector to look at the computed style of the body and also the inheritance / overriding of CSS rules that result in this computed style.

If you set `document.body.style.backgroundColor` (not the `bgColor` property) you'll see that you can actually change the background color here. It all depends on whether there is another rule somewhere else with higher specificity or not. The DOM inspector will tell you whether that's the case.

Comment: +1, think we should propose this on meta should we? `document.body.style.background = "pink";`

Comment: @Jeroen It actually doesn't look too bad.

Answer (score 3):

CSS is your answer.  Try

```
document.body.style.background="red";
```

CSS styles supersede element properties.

Comment: Are you saying by doing this, the background color will change no matter what the css implementation the site is using, because it is superseding?

Comment: Well, yes.  The background of the page will change color.  That may not change the color you see - many, many sites use a container div that has its own background color, or divs within divs that have background colors.

Answer (score 3):

If you do that, the background will change here too. But as you can see with a DOM Inspector, the background isn't the thing which you really see. This is a `div` called `container`. If you change the background of this div, you'll see the changes

Edit: Ohh i see the container is transperent. So use `document.body.style.backgroundColor` then it will work. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the color of the body background. However, that does not necessarily reflect the background of the current view. Moreover, if there are more specific definitions in place for an element than the definition you impose, they will still be used. So, there is no "why not" because you are correct: you can always change the page locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can change background color of body in html. use css property like this code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body { 
            background-color: red  
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

You can check more property to changing the color of body by this link
http://www.webclasses.in/css-background/

Comment: Note that this question is about changing the background colour programmatically through Javascript, not basic CSS properties.

Answer (score -2):

```
document.backgroundColor="red";
```